# Should I always return nil in ruby methods?

Tags: ruby

As we know functions have side-effects and/or return values, and methods have only side-effects. So for a performance/memory perspective is it better to return `nil` at the end of ruby methods.

For example if I have a method that adds a hash to an existing hash like this:

```ruby
def add_to_config(config)
  config[:alphabet] = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
end
```

We know that the return value of this method is the item assigned, in this case the alphabet hash. Now in this trivial example doesn't seem like a big deal. But what happens when it's a big complex data structure that is assigned?

Is it better to explicitly return `nil` to prevent the bigger data structure from being returned?

```ruby
def add_to_config(config)
  config[:alphabet] = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
  nil
end
```

Or does it really matter? Since it's just probably pushing a pointer into the stack -- speculation, I have no idea how ruby does it.

Comment: "So for a performance/memory perspective is it better to return nil at the end of ruby methods." what is your reason for thinking so?

Comment: From my old `c` programming days I know that return values get pushed on the stack frame and the calling function needs to pop them out. I would think that ruby works in a similar way and if returning nil all this push and pop would be avoided thus less memory use and less clock cycles required

Comment: ruby is designed for programmer happiness and while there are times when optimizing is important this probably isn't one of them, considering that the return value will be garbage-collected unless it's assigned to a variable. However it's helpful to document when methods only use side effects. There's a convention to add a bang (`!`) at the end of the method name, and some people do choose to explicitly return nil, but it's more for clarity's sake than performance.

Comment: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-c-and-cpp/
"All variables live on the heap. Further, you don’t need to free them yourself—the garbage collector takes care of that."
"There’s no macros or preprocessor. No casts. No pointers (nor pointer arithmetic). No typedefs, sizeof, nor enums."

Also ruby is implemented in C ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start, methods also have return values with optional side effects. Further Ruby has methods only, and not functions. A bit of code defined outside a module or a class is a method of the default main object which is Object class.

In cases where there are only side effects and no return value, conventional wisdom is to return self. This allows methods to be chained:

```
obj.method_one(args).method_two(args).method_three(args)
```

as opposed to:

```
obj.method_one(args)
obj.method_two(args)
obj.method_three(args)
```

While a minor point, every method always has access to its self, while nil would be a reference to a special global object. This could possibly be faster, but not enough to ever be important.

Source code above is shown for illustration only and not intended to start a holy war on source code formatting.